# Is there a top rank users with more hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash

Is there a top rank users with more hats?

I'm just curious to see the first ones.

Comment: Are you looking for this http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @NathanOliver. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the leader board for the hats at the [Stack Exchange Leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard)

If you just want to see the one for Stack Overflow then you can go to the [Stack Overflow Leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com)